# How can I change default role in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Due to the audit security, If I wouldn't revoke the privilege from the public role

can I change the default role in the Oracle database from 'PUBLIC' to another default group?

then I create a new user I would like it to create under the new default?

Thanks and Best Regards,

Comment: I think **every** user gets the `PUBLIC` role granted - that's the purpose of public and you cannot change it. Revoke non-desired privileges from PUBLIC role. Actually while working for 20 years with Oracle I never granted anything to `PUBLIC`.

Comment: PUBLIC includes necessary system-level grants for all users. Oracle no longer recommends revoking privileges from PUBLIC, and you cannot revoke the PUBLIC role itself from users. Application-specific grants should be made to separate application-specific roles.